# How to fill float value to a float type column of virtual table feeded via plugin written using MYSQL C++ API without cropping?

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a Innodb plugin. In the plugin code I declared the type of the column as "MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT" and when I am feeding a float value to it via 'table->field[m] -> store(f1, TRUE);' where f1 = 3.145 its cropping.

In my case it made it 3 instead of the expected 3.145.

So please suggest me how to feed float without cropping.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with my question.The solution is while defining the fields for the plugin table we have to take MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT as type for column and the value we are going to feed in this column must be of type double for getting the proper value in the table.